# Ошибка Timed out receiving message from renderer: 60.000

Tags: java, maven, test-automation, jenkins

Всем привет!

Уже неделю не могу решить проблему с прогоном своего проекта.
Использую maven и serenity-bdd.
Все началось с того, что на одном шаге с выпадающим списком периодически падали сценарии с ошибкой:

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 60.000
```

Я пытался бороться с этим - увеличивал таймаут до 2 минут, обновил все в pom.xml до последних версий, драйвер и браузер тоже обновил, прописал в serenity.properties:

```
chrome.switches=--disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows, \
                --no-sandbox, \
                --disable-infobars, \
                --disable-dev-shm-usage, \
                --disable-browser-side-navigation, \
                --disable-gpu
```

Мне ничего не помогает. Ошибка остается.
Обычно она появляется на строчках с вызовом скрипта скролла:

```
public void scrollToWithOffset(WebElementFacade element) {
    final JavascriptExecutor driver = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriver();
    try {
        driver.executeScript("window.scrollTo({ top: arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect().top - 90, behavior: 'smooth' });",
                             element);
        element.withTimeoutOf(5, ChronoUnit.SECONDS)
               .waitUntilVisible();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'instant', block: 'center' });",
                             element);
    }
}
```

И с такой проблемой я сталкиваюсь в прогоне по 4-5 раз + время прогона может увеличиться с 1 часа до 4-8 часов. В один такой момент я решил посмотреть что происходит на удаленной машине, а там просто открыта 1 копия браузера (хотя 4 потока установлено) с открытым сайтом и ничего не происходит. Из-за этого установил в Jenkins "Abort the build if it's stuck" на 1 час. И теперь каждый прогон у меня падает с ошибкой застревания.

Может кто-то подскажет куда смотреть/что делать в данной ситуации. Я уже не знаю куда копать.
Это мой первый вопрос на данном ресурсе, так что не будьте строги.
Если понадобится дополнительная информация - я ее предоставлю.

Comment: страница полностью загружена? (все запросы в network имеют конечный статус)

Comment: @Ruslan да. Разобрался с данным вопросом давно, но уже не помню каким образом)